# html tags considered as plain text when using angular directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

for example:

function `foo()` located in my controller:

```
              $scope.getOffers = function(){
                 var txt1="aaaa"+"<br>"+"bbbb";
                  $scope.newData = txt1;
              };
```

and my html:

```
                <div class="help-block" ng-show="newData ">{{ offers }}</div>
```

and when I called  `foo()` the text that showed up was:
`aaaa<br>bbbb`
instead of :

```
        aaaa
        bbbb
```

(I already tried to insert `\n` in my text...)
What am I missing? and how can I fix the problem?

thanks!

Comment: you *can* use helpers like `.trustAsHtml()` or `ng-bind-html` to help with this, but if you are trying to structure your variables to hold HTML in the first place, you are probably not fully embracing the angular paradigm.

Comment: try with ng-bind-html-unsafe, you can check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VFVMv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And don't forget to trust the html. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

See this plunker
http://embed.plnkr.co/HAKJ2iknZeeEOsgukoGd/

Comment: thanks! the combinition of the 2 answers is perfect! Can you please  tell me what is ` $sce`?

Answer (score 1):

you need use **[ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)** for this

```
 <div class="help-block" ng-show="newData " ng-bind-html="offers"></div>
```